# Apache thrift error while compiling on windows

Tags: windows, cmake, thrift

I am trying to compile the Apache thrift version 0.10.0 on my windows 10 machine. For compilation purpose, I am using CMake scripts provided by apache thrift. However, I am not able to compile because I found something called

> Performing Test STRERROR_R_CHAR_P
>
> -- Performing Test STRERROR_R_CHAR_P - Failed.

I don't know what is the issue here. I tried everything but no luck.

I am using Visual Studio 15, cmake version 3.7.0.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad...

I missed onto.

> boost_system
>    boost_thread

after installing these two I was able to resolve the error. I see there is not any detailed article on how to build thrift using CMake. Soon, I will write a post and share here. Thank you.